# using os.path is quite verbose is there a more concise way to manipulate paths

Tags: python, path

for example I have a script that needs to put it's parent directory on the python path, currently I'm using the following

```
sys.path += [os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))]
```

this seems a touch ridiculous, surely there is a simpler way?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what's the purpose of using dirname twice?

Comment: @John: `foo/bar/baz.py`. `dirname` once gives `foo/bar`, `dirname` twice gives `foo`.

Comment: What's ridiculous about it? That you have to call os.path.dirname to remove a path component?

Comment: If these answers answer the question, can you accept one? (ghostdog74's is the most compact, using stdlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
from os.path import dirname,realpath
sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(realpath(__file__))))
```

But to be honest, I prefer the full explicit version. It's much easier to read as a standalone statement.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Jason Orendorff's path module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py) to be very nice.  Unfortunately, it seems that his website is no longer on the internet, but you can still [download the module from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/path.py/path-2.2.zip).

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
>>> from os.path import dirname as dn, realpath as rp
```

but its still better to explicitly define the name so you won't have variable names collision problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to import path from os. It's not the *most consise* but I think it's still easy to read. Do you really want us to golf it? :)

```
from os import path
sys.path += [path.dirname(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a huge problem, you could wrap os.path functionality is a path class.  I'm pretty sure there is a Path module floating around on the internet.